# Which Multi-platform app development framework is better for background service/synchronization on both Android and iOS?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, xamarin, android-service

I am looking for a Multi-platform mobile app development framework.
Key features i require are:

- Support for Background Services for synchronization
- Database support

Which frameworks are better suite for these?

My research comparing React Native and Xamarin so far says that react native used more often in industry and has more developer support available but officially they only have 'headless-js-android' for Android for running services. Xamarin on the other hand has the support for running services on both platforms.

I need some guidance from someone who has worked with both technologies.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The following is a list of multi-platform mobile apps development frameworks:

- Adobe PhoneGap: https://phonegap.com/
- Appcelerator Titanium: http://www.appcelerator.com
- Sencha Touch: http://www.sencha.com/products/touch
- Ionic: https://ionicframework.com/
- Sinpalm: http://www.simpalm.com/services/sencha-touch-development-developer

Check them out and let me know which one got your attention.

This is an oversimplification on the way they work:

- They allow you to create a user interface with HTML5 and JavaScript.
- Then, via JavaScript injection, they provide you with a standard API framework.

  - This JS API framework is a common interface to both Android and iOS. Therefore, you only focus on coding against the JavaScript API framework. Behind the scenes, they have libraries that will execute this API in the respective device.

[image]

Most of them allow you to use the database and other features provided by the respective OS (Android/iOS). You only need to check which supports the feature you need better.

Comment: Not looking for hybrid app development frameworks but rather Native app development frameworks specifically with good support for background data sync and background services for mobile platforms

Comment: you asked for multi platform app development framework.... which would NOT be native. perhaps you have no idea what you want? react native is another good option.... if you want native, android studio (java or kotlin) or xcode (swift or objective c) in your tags you mentioned xamarin and react native. ... again, these are NOT native.

Comment: @DroidDev frameworks that get compiled into a native app rather than a web app running in a webview ... e.g. "Flutter is Google’s mobile app SDK for crafting high-quality native interfaces on iOS and Android in record time"

Comment: @AsifAltaf Don't get it wrong but... How does Flutter do it? What is the process they used? How do they convert and keep up with changes on both Frameworks then? As far as the quote goes, it doesn't explain these questions and sounds like something coming out from the marketing department. However, if Flutter is what you were searching for, then I am happy for you and I hope you keep us updated since we are curious.